# In Visio 2013 How do you set image location from shape data?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

In Visio 2013, you can insert a picture from a URL/hyperlink:

```
Insert > Pictures > [http://someurl] > Open
```

Visio will contact the remote server, download the image and display it.

Is it possible to achieve this dynamically using External Data and Shape Data?
For example, if I have a table of clients and their logos, can I bind the logo to a shape in Visio?

```
ClientCode    ClientName   ClientLogo
GOOG          Google, Inc. https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
MSFT          Microsoft    https://assets.onestore.ms/cdnfiles/external/uhf/long/9a49a7e9d8e881327e81b9eb43dabc01de70a9bb/images/microsoft-gray.png
```

I tried to view shape data for the picture after inserting it - hoping that it would have an `Image Path` attribute or similar - however, the shape data shows empty.

[image: No Shape Data for Pictures in Visio]

If it's not possible in 2013, how about 2016?

Answer (score 1):

If you create excel table with rows containing your clients, and bind it to the diagram, you should be able to see a hyperlink to the picture in the shape data (by using stock sharepoint visio services).

For more advanced functionality, you could check out [this extension](http://unmanagedvisio.com/products/svg-publish/) (disclaimer: i'm the author), that can export visio diagrams as svg, embedding some javascript to allow a bit better interactivity than stock Visio services.

Sample: [Pokemon Office](https://nbelyh.github.io/svgpublishdemo/PokemonBldgPlan.html) (try clicking the shapes).

The list of pictures and properties is defined in excel. Please see the [corresponding post](http://unmanagedvisio.com/pokemon-office-more-html-popovers/).

Comment: Thanks for this. It only partly answers my question - I have already linked my clients table to the diagram and I can bind it to the Shape Data. My question is - once I have a URL bound to a shape, how can I get Visio to load the image data from the URL to display that image on my diagram? I want my report to display a client logo and I want it to update automatically if the logo url is updated. By the way, your export tool looks awesome and suits some of my requirements so I'll definitely be looking into it deeper!

Comment: There is no such out-of-the-box function, as of my knowledge. You'll need some additional custom code to make it happen.

Comment: Ok - so the only way is using a tool like yours and then using JavaScript to enhance? If so can you point me towards any similar code samples for your tool and i'll look into it. Once the diagram is exported, am I able to refresh its data using your tool directly from the web app or would I need to open Visio, refresh the data and re-export every time? (easily done in powershell these days!)

Comment: You can go with VBA macro for example. Or with custom js in the SharePoint Visio services

Comment: I want to host this externally to Sharepoint for integration with another application. I'll probably go with js approach